# How can I get a user access token for a specific facebook test user?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, access-token, facebook-access-token, facebook-test-users

According to [Facebook Devlopers: Test Users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/), I can list the test users of my facebook app by making a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`. The response includes a valid user access token for each user.

How can I get a valid user access token for a specific test user without downloading the whole list of test users?

Comment: You have to download the list and parse the ID and access_token of one of those users

Answer (score 0):

Test users *should* be able to be authenticated with your application in the same way as an other user. So use the Authentication flows while logged in for a specific test user.

Other than that there is no way to call one by one without parsing with code.

Comment: But is there a way to get a token ? I'd like to use it in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: test user's token is returned by the test users api. some libraries running around facebook apis also do that, for instance, http://code.google.com/p/facebook-test-java-api/ returns access token for the FacebookTestUser object